# Value of string returned from UStats.getForegroundAppPackagename()

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app for *Android Marshmallow*. It must recognize when [waze](https://www.waze.com/) (GPS navigation software) is on foreground and then remove a popup from the screen. In order to do that it uses this system's function `UStats.getForegroundAppPackagename` as stated above.

I've control of the whole system source code therefore I changed the framework to always grant `usagestat` permission for my application.
In most cases the function works fine, however sometimes when *waze* is 
stuck in calculations the function returns nothing . Meaning I've the following code:

```
String foregroundTask =
UStats.getForegroundAppPackagename(this);
Log.d(TAG, "foregroundTask = " + foregroundTask);
```

The log prints `foregroundTask=`

First of all, what is the value returned by the function? an empty strings? it's obviously not null.

Second, does anyone know how is possible the function returns that value? and in which cases?

Thank you.

Comment: we don't know what UStats class you use, we don't know what parameter you pass to it. How would we know? debug your code, and check the value for yourself

Comment: my mistake you are right, i will edit the question

Comment: if we can see what String it returns by that, so can you

Comment: I have answered it: "debug your code, and check the value for yourself". Again: I have no idea what UStats class you use, nor do I find documentation for it.